# C# MVC Bundle - Check to see if Files are in a Bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am currently working on a C# MVC project that, based on site definitions will load a bundle for that site. However, not all sites has files in their bundles (the do have a definition however in BundleConfig.cs).

**BundleConfig.cs code snippet**

```
var BHICustomBundles = BHI.WCMS.Helper.Configuration.CustomSiteConfigurationManager.getBundles();
foreach (var item in BHICustomBundles)
{
    // Set up JavaScript Bundle
    if ((item.JavascriptBundle != null) && (item.JavascriptBundle.Count > 0))
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/CustomJS_" + item.name).Include(item.JavascriptBundle.ToArray()));
    }
    else
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/CustomJS_" + item.name));
    }

    // Set up CSS Bundle
    if ((item.CssBundle != null) && (item.CssBundle.Count > 0))
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/CustomCSS_" + item.name).Include(item.CssBundle.ToArray()));
    }
    else
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/CustomCSS_" + item.name));
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I go through a configuration file, and add in a custom ScriptBundle and StyleBundle per location in the configuration file. (this is in SiteCore, so each definition is handles separately, and this works)

Now, the configuration section looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CustomSiteConfiguration>
    <Sites>
        <Site siteRoot="/Partner" name="Partner_en">
            <siteSettings>
                <setting name="" value="" />
            </siteSettings>
            <JavaScriptBundles>
                <file name="" />
            </JavaScriptBundles>
            <CSSBundles>
                <file name="" />
            </CSSBundles>
        </Site>
    </Sites>
 </CustomSiteConfiguration>
```

Each section is optional. So, a particular site may not have a bundle (or files), however, I am including the bundle (because it exists in BundleConfig.cs)

This is the default.aspx page snippet including the bundle

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/CustomCSS_" + Sitecore.Context.Site.Name) %>    <%-- Added for custom CSS bundle - rwh2 2016-05-18 --%>
```

What I am hoping to do is make this a conditional statement that would make sure there is something there to render, if not, then don't render (because we are trying to optimize load time.

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So why not put your condition in your aspx page like this:
`If(condtionmet){
<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/CustomCSS_" + Sitecore.Context.Site.Name) %>    <%-- Added for custom CSS bundle - rwh2 2016-05-18 --%>}`

Comment: I agree that I want to add the condition, however, I am not certain what the condition would be to state that the bundle is not empty. The first thought it to write a static function (Boolean) that would check the item count inside the config file, however, I was trying to avoid that and see if there was something pre-built into .Net that would tell me how many items are in a Bundle

Comment: `IsSectionDefined("MySpecialScripts")` could solve your problem then

Comment: I added a second function for this, and was able to check the boolean against that, That is working for us now, and is in production. Thanks for your help @ShashankSood

Comment: Your welcome.. Please upvote my comment then ;)